# Minimum value of volume of solid created by rotating $f(x) = \frac{p^2}{x^p}$ about $x$-axis from $[1,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, solid-of-revolution

*The question is: For any positive real number p, define f(x) = $\frac{p^2}{x^p}$ Find the minimum value of the volume of the solid created by rotating this function around the x-axis over the interval [1,∞)*

When I tried to solve this problem by using integration of f(x) from 1 to ∞, I am getting $\frac{p}{1-p}$ as my answer for the volume.

I'm not sure if this is correct. Appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: integration of $f$? what does that have to do with volume?

Answer (score 2):

For the integral to converge, we need $p\in[1/2,+\infty$).The volume equals

\begin{align}
V&=\pi\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{p^2}{x^{2p}}\,dx \\ 
&=p^2 \pi \left[ \frac{x^{1-2p}}{1-2p}\Biggr|_1^{+\infty} \right] \\ 
&= \frac{\pi p^2}{2p-1}
\end{align}
Differentiating with respect to $p$ and setting $\frac{dV}{dp}=0$,

\begin{align}
\frac{dV}{dp}=\pi\frac{(2p-1)2p-2p^2}{(2p-1)^2}=0
&\implies 2p^2-2p=0 \\
&\implies p(p-1)=0 \\
&\implies p=1
\end{align}

The minimum volume is therefore 
$$V_{min}=\pi$$

If you want to show that this is indeed a minimum, you can compute $V''(1)$:
$$V''(1)=2\pi>0$$
Our result is thus a minimum.

EDIT:

If $f(x)=\frac{p^2}{x^p}$, then

\begin{align}
V&=\pi\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{p^4}{x^{2p}}\,dx \\ \\
&=\frac{\pi p^4}{2p-1}
\end{align}
Then setting $V'(p)=0$ in order to minimize $V(p)$, we find that 
\begin{align}
V'(p)&=\pi \frac{(2p-1)4p^3 - 2p^4}{(2p-1)^2}= 0 \\ \\ 
&\implies 6p^4 - 4p^3=0 \\ 
&\implies p^3(3p-2)=0 \\
&\implies p=\frac{2}{3} \quad \text{ since } p\in\mathbb{R}^+
\end{align}

The minimum volume is then

$$V_{min}=\frac{16\pi}{27}$$

And, again, you can check that this is indeed a minimum by evaluating $V''(2/3)$. Indeed,

$$V''(2/3)=16\pi > 0 $$
This means that our volume is indeed a minimum.

Comment: Hi, the original function was actually $f(x) = \frac{p^2}{x^p}$ , I missed out the $p^2$ part there. Would you mind redoing it with the changes? Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting 16π/27 when I recalculate, would that be correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct! I edited my post!